# pygame.mixer.init() gvies weird error while loading file

Tags: python, pygame, runtime-error

I am trying to play a '.mp3' file through pygame.mixer.music at a changed frequency. It was working perfectly fine in my old PC. I have recently moved the program to my new PC and gives the following error:

```
pygame.error: Could not initialize MPEG stream.
```

and sometimes I get:

```
pygame.error: failed loading libmpg123.dll: attempt to access invalid address.
```

These errors occur alternatively(Extremely strange).And these errors point to the line:

```
pygame.mixer.load(m)
```

Another thing that I noted was that my code works perfectly fine if this statement:

```
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=26000)
```

is changed into:

```
pygame.mixer.init()
```

My pygame version is 1.9.6 in both my Laptops. The python version is 3.7.x in old one and 3.8.x in new one.
The entire code is below:

```
def assistant_speaks(*texts):
    for text in texts:
        song_file = "temp.mp3"
        speech = gTTS(text=text, lang='en-us', slow=False)
        speech.save(song_file) 

        audio_length = MP3(song_file).info.length

        print(text2)

        mixer.init(frequency=26500)
        with open(song_file) as f:
            m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
        mixer.music.load(m)
        mixer.music.play()
        sleep(audio_length) 
        mixer.music.stop()
        mixer.quit()
        pygame.quit()
        m.close()
        os.remove(song_file)
```

I have tried reinstalling pygame multiple times. I use sublime text and kite to code. I have even reinstalled python.

Any help on how to fix this would greatly be appreciated. Thank you in Advance!
Or also you can suggest me any other module to alter the frequency and play.

**EDIT:**
I have been able to make it work by unistalling python 3.8 and installing python 3.7 . Looks like this problem is present in python 3.8 only. Should I report this ? How?

Answer (score 0):

Update pygame to 2.0.0.dev6 or newer. This should fix the issue.
`pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but then I have tried it. Then I get a new error: pygame.error mod_plug load failed.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I run my programs on window's command prompt. But I think python IDE is installed by default (I haven't used it at all).

Comment: Is your .mp3 file in the same directory, or your relative path correct?

Comment: The .mp3 file is in the same directory. As you can see in the program, the file is just created in the first part of the function.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to solve the issue, I had similar problem and updating pygame solved it..

Comment: Thank you for trying. As for the problem I'll try updating pygame one last time.